# c# mass image changer

Tags: c#, image

im trying to create program that changes format of imported images i dont know how to save it any help would be appreciated 
--Edit; im trying save each file imported to specific folder with selected format
my code ;

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (String file in dialog.FileNames)
            {
                    listView1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
                    string filee = saveFileDialog1.FileName;


            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
            listView1.Items.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you should clarify what you exactly need, what is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: There is a lot more involved than just changing an images extension..

Comment: sorry edited now should be more clear

Comment: You haven't tried anything of what you actually asked

Comment: i dont know what to try ?

Comment: Have you considered possibility that `Image` class has `Save` method for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(inputFilename);
image.Save(outputFileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

That should do it, if I'm not mistaken. You load an image into memory from a file, then save it given whatever format you want, I chose gif here as an example.

Comment: Does this actually convert the file to the desired format or just change the file extension?

Comment: It changes the format. In fact, it's up to you to change the extension that you pass into `outputFileName`.

Comment: And there I always ended up doing a Graphic and redrew the image so I could save it in a different format.